# cakephp how to create and save form with one date and time interval

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Cakephp 3.2

I have [start_time]&[end_time]datetime field in MYSQL table.

and I have form as [Form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYHWj.png)

now I want to save date and time interval as you can see in image.

how to set [start_time]&[end_time] with same date and how to save and display the saved date and time interval to view

I'm new to this PHP world
I will appreciate your help

my ctp HTML file looks like this

```
<tr>
    <th>date</th>
    <th class="require"><span class="red">※</span></th>
    <td colspan="3">
        <input type="text" class="calendar" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select>
            <!-- hour -->
            <option value="1">0</option>
        </select>：
        <select>
            <!-- minutes -->
            <option value="0">00</option>
        </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;～&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select>
            <!-- hour -->
            <option value="1">0</option>
        </select>：
        <select>
            <!-- minutes -->
            <option value="">00</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this is a small demo, please refer the cakephp portal to learn in depth.

take the table inside a form

now you have 3 fields -

> date - text field : name it as input_date

> 2 time fields (drop-downs):
> hour : name it as start_tm[0] ( `$this->Form->select('start_tm.0',[values here],[options]);` )

> minute : name it as start_tm[1]

likewise - end_tm[0],end_tm[1]

## at the controller

// let say your model name is "TimeSlots"

`$data = $this->request->getData();` // get the request data ( post )

// do validations serverside .............. ( i have not added )

// format the input as required by your db table

```
$start_time_text = $data['input_date'] . ' ' . implode(':',$data['start_tm']); 
$end_time_text = $data['input_date'] . ' ' . implode(':',$data['end_tm']);
```

// ( your date text will now look like yyyy/mm/dd h:mm )

// formatting as date time text

```
 $data['start_time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_time_text)); 
    $data['end_time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end_time_text));

$timeSlot = $this->TimeSlots->newEntity($data); // you can set validation at the model - see cakephp ORM

if($this->TimeSlots->save($timeSlot)){
    $this->Flash->success(__('Saved successfully'));
} else {
    $this->Flash->success(__('Some error occurred'));
}
```